# NVMe M.2 SSD missing after a windows update reboot + slow booting time since

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, nvme

I have 2 x `970 EVO Samsung NVMe M2` SSD on my motherboard.

The first one is where windows is installed on and it's working fine.
The second one is the one (now) missing that I use as a normal storage drive.

Everything was working fine before I restart the computer to apply a windows update earlier today. I even browsed files with the explorer on the NVMe just before restarting.

- When starting the computer, it stay on the motherboard logo longer that usual (about a few minutes) and then it load windows and takes additional time. It was a lot faster before.
- The missing NVMe is not listed in the BIOS since the update reboot.
- I tried switching both NVMe to be sure that the issue is not from the socket or motherboard, but it still does not display the missing NVMe in the BIOS.
- I have tried booting with a live flash version of `gparted` but it does not display the missing NVMe (it only see the one with windows on it. Same thing in BIOS)
- Checking Windows `Device Manager` display a warning on one of the NVM Express Controller `This device cannot start. (Code 10) An I/O adapter hardware error has occurred.`

[image]

- Both my NVMe are encrypted with Bitlocker if that matter.
- The windows update is `KB5022476`
- I also found this error before the restart:
  [image]
- I get a `cx_Freeze Fatal Error / cannot get zipimporter instance` when windows start since a couple of months now, but don't think it's related since everything was working fine for months (My computer and my NVMe drives are 2 years old btw...)

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Not commenting on your current issue but the Fatal Error: "Cx_ze Fatal Error Cannot Get Zipimport and other critical errors can occur when your Windows operating system becomes corrupted. Opening programs will be slower and response times will lag." From https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cxfreeze-fatal-error-cannot-get-zipimporter/804fe57f-b797-49ae-a8e9-401b06ddfe59.

Comment: Any hints in SMART, does it list the drive even?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen what is SMART? The device is not event listed in the BIOS